There is no file linux/init.h
I'm trying to write my own pci-device driver on an Ubuntu system.
The example I found says that I need:
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>

I'm using Qt and it underlines the first include as a mistake.
When I put the mouse cursor under the 2nd or 3rd line, it shows me a tip: /usr/include/linux/module.h or /usr/include/linux/pci.h, so I opened /usr/include/linux in file explorer, and there is no init.h.
I ran sudo apt install linux-headers-generic but it didn't help.
locate linux/init.h gives:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-121/include/linux/init.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-122/include/linux/init.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-43/include/linux/init.h

So is my problem that I have to add something to my PATH or do I have to install something else?
Yes, I've seen a lot of topics about people having problems with compiling something because of linux/init.h: no such file or directory, but I am not compiling, I can't even include it.

"I can't even include it" I wouldn't necessarily expect an IDE to be aware of the kbuild framework - afaik the usual kernel module build process involves invoking make with a suitable -C build directory argument that will allow it to find the headers. See for example Compiling kernel modules

Try sudo apt install build-essential. It's a metapackage that includes all that you need.

@waltinator, it says "build-essential is already the newest version"

ok, i figured it out. it's impossible to write driver in qt because it's using userspace libraries but you need kernelspace libraries so drivers has to be written in notepad/vim/smthlikethat
